# Method Illuminate\Http\Request::first does not exist in laravel 6 error

Tags: validation, laravel-6

I am trying to implement multiple column as unique(title,created_by). A user can not create duplicate title.
The validation give me error both in separate request class also.
The validation code is:

```
    $created_by = auth()->user()->id;
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:50|unique:register_types,title,null,id,created_by,'.$created_by
    ]);
```

The code give error as "Method Illuminate\Http\Request::first does not exist"

But Validator method works successfully.
The code is:

```
    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'title' => 'required|max:50|unique:register_types,title,null,id,created_by,'.$created_by
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $validator->errors();
    }
```

I want to use first clean code pattern. How is it possible ?

Comment: I think you need to change $request to $request->all() on $this->validate()

Comment: No, It takes only instance not array.

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem.
Some days ago, I have added a condition at render method in handler class:

```
    elseif ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
        return $exception->first();
    }
```

Solution:
At this time, just I blocked this condition. 
Problem solved.